# Sin datos en un jTable cuando añado un segundo jTable en un mismo jFrame

Tags: java, sql, netbeans-8.2

Verán, tengo un jFrame donde he puesto un jTabbedPane y dentro hay 3 jPanels. En el primer jPanel, he puesto un jTable para mostrar unos datos de la BD y ha ido todo bien.

```
private void cargarTablaAlumnos(String SQL){
    try{
        Connection con2 = ConexionDB.GetConnection();
        Statement stmt2 = null;
        ResultSet rs2 = null;

        alumnosModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        alumnosModel.setRowCount(0);
        alumnosModel.addColumn("Alumno");
        alumnosModel.addColumn("Profesor");
        alumnosModel.addColumn("Clase");
        alumnosModel.addColumn("Curso");
        alumnosModel.addColumn("Fecha Alta");

        stmt2 = con2.createStatement();
        stmt2.executeUpdate(SQL);

        this.SQL = "SELECT * FROM #tmp_alumnos";
        rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(this.SQL);

        while(rs2.next()){
            alumnosModel.addRow(new Object[]{rs2.getString("nombre_alumno"),rs2.getString("nombre_profesor"),rs2.getString("curso"),rs2.getString("codigo"), rs2.getString("fecha_alta")});
        }

        t_matricula_alumnos.setModel(alumnosModel);

        rs2.close();
        stmt2.close();
        con2.close();
    } catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
}`
```

`El problema es que al poner un segundo jTable en el segundo jPanel, deja de funcionarme el primer jTable y solo me funciona el segundo:

```
private void cargarTablaAsistenciaAlumnos(String SQL){
    try{
        Connection con2 = ConexionDB.GetConnection();
        Statement stmt2 = null;
        ResultSet rs2 = null;
        GlobalProject.criterio = "Cursos.ConsultarAsistencia";
        TableCellRenderer tcr = new TableCellRenderer();

        alumnosAsistModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        alumnosAsistModel.setRowCount(0);
        alumnosAsistModel.addColumn("Alumno");
        alumnosAsistModel.addColumn("Curso");
        alumnosAsistModel.addColumn("Clase");
        alumnosAsistModel.addColumn("Fecha");
        alumnosAsistModel.addColumn("Asistio");

        stmt2 = con2.createStatement();
        rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(SQL);

        while(rs2.next()){
            alumnosAsistModel.addRow(new Object[]{rs2.getString("nombre"),rs2.getString("codigo"),rs2.getString("curso"),rs2.getString("fecha"), rs2.getInt("asistio")});
        }

        t_asistenciaAlumnos.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, tcr);
        t_asistenciaAlumnos.setModel(alumnosAsistModel);
        this.hideColumnFromTableAsistAlumnos(4);

        rs2.close();
        stmt2.close();
        con2.close();
    } catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Después de darle muchas vueltas, he eliminado momentáneamente el segundo jTable, y al ejecutar ... sorpresa! el primer jTable (el único que hay en todo el jFrame, ahora) me carga de nuevo los datos. Añado de nuevo el segundo jTable y deja de funcionar el primer jTable de nuevo para que ahora solo funcione el segundo jTable.

He puesto el debug y veo que alumnosModel contiene toda la informacion del rs2, pero al hacer t_matricula_alumnos.setModel(alumnosModel); no lo coge.

Es un bug? Es como si hubiera algún problema raro con los punteros de las tablas ...

He probado con lo siguiente pero tampoco me ha funcionado.

```
t_matricula_alumnos.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));
```

En resumen, que solo puedo tener un JTable, si añado un segundo, el primero deja de cargar datos y se queda vació.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!

He eliminado el segundo jTable (el que funcionaba tanto si había otro jTable como si no) y he eliminado tambié el jScrollPane relacionado con esta table. He vuelto a crear la tabla de nuevo, le he dado un nombre al jScrollPane y a la tabla también y listo!

Sigo con la incógnita de si se trataba de un bug. Tiene pinta, pero no lo puedo asegurar.